# Como saber de qual State estou vindo, usando ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estou usando ui-router do Angular-Ui e a unica coisa que eu preciso saber é de qual state estou vindo.
Já tenho por exemplo;

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope,$state) {
    //$state.current ok, mas de onde eu vim?    
});
```

**Como saber qual state anterior chamou o** `current`**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este recurso foi sugerido no repositório do ui-router ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/92) (em inglês)) e parece ter um *feedback* positivo, mas por enquanto ainda não há uma forma simplificada de se obter esta informação.

Uma possível *workaround* apontada nos comentários da *issue* mencionada anteriormente é escutar o evento `$stateChangeSuccess` na `$rootScope`, cujo *callback* recebe o objeto do `$state` anterior como argumento, podendo assim salvá-lo na `$rootScope`. Desta forma, os dados do `$state` anterior ficam acessíveis em todos escopos que herdam da `$rootScope`. [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XjxXFYHjRSlYQ8Vnv3TB?p=preview):

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $rootScope.previousState = fromState;
  });
})
.controller("State1Ctrl", function($scope, $state) {
  console.log($scope.previousState, $scope.previousState.name);
})
.controller("State2Ctrl", function($scope, $state) {
  console.log($scope.previousState, $scope.previousState.name);
});
```